# Count on various substrings from same column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to count the number of occurences of several substrings from the same column and with the same WHERE condition. For each substring I have a UNION SELECT statement including the repeating WHERE condition. The final result is a query with appox. 2500 lines of sql code, but it gives good result.

Simplified example of query:

```
SELECT ‘be’ AS country, count(destination) FROM demo
WHERE destination LIKE ‘%be%’ AND field_a=xzx AND field_b=bbb

UNION SELECT ‘de’ AS country, count(destination) FROM demo
WHERE destination LIKE ‘%de%’ AND field_a=xzx AND field_b=bbb

UNION SELECT ‘fr’ AS country, count(destination) FROM demo
WHERE destination LIKE ‘%fr%’ AND field_a=xzx AND field_b=bbb

UNION SELECT ‘nl’ AS country, count(destination) FROM demo
WHERE destination LIKE ‘%nl%’ AND field_a=xzx AND field_b=bbb
```

Is it possible to modify the query in such a way that the WHERE condition only appears once in the query?

Please find a simplified example of my question via this link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1otjZZlBy6au5E2I7T6NdSYmLayhNGWyXGxGo3gBx_-w/edit

Comment: Normalize your database, the table Demo should have different columns for destinations. Even better, a separate table for destinations is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DON'T*** store comma separated values in a single field. Instead, use a many:many relationship table and store one (id,country) combination per row. Your data structure is a SQL-Anti-Pattern and goes against all relational database design principles.

```
CREATE TABLE map (
  demo_id INT,
  country VARCHAR(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (demo_id, country)
)

INSERT INTO map VALUES
  (1, 'nl'), (1, 'de'), (1, 'be'), (1, 'fr'),
  (2, 'de'), (2, 'fr'), (2, 'be'),
  (3, 'fr'), (3, 'nl'),
  (4, 'nl')
```

Then you will have this single query...

```
SELECT
  map.country,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  demo
INNER JOIN
  map
    ON map.demo_id = demo.id
WHERE
      demo.field_a = 'xzx'
  AND demo.field_b = 'bbb'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.country,count(*) from
(
select 'be' as country
union all
select 'de' as country
union all
select 'fr' as country
union all
select 'nl' as country
)a join demo d
on d.destination like '%'+a.country+'%'
AND d.field_a=xzx AND d.field_b=bbb
group by a.country
```

I am not sure whether mySQL supports derived table or not . If its not supported the you have to create a temp table with all different country values and replace it with table a in the above query

Comment: Ideally, the OP should already have unique list of countries in an entity / dimension table.  I would up-vote this, but I can't up-vote anything that uses `,` in preference to ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax.  `,` isn't even recommend by the RDBMS systems that support it (most actually actively recommend *against* its use), it's just plain bad practice, sorry.

Comment: @Dems- Thanks for the information.. I will change it to join, and I will keep it mind henceforth

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END`

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN destination LIKE "%be%" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "BE",
COUNT(CASE WHEN destination LIKE "%fr%" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "FR",
COUNT(CASE WHEN destination LIKE "%de%" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "DE",
COUNT(CASE WHEN destination LIKE "%nl%" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "NL"
FROM demo
WHERE field_a = "xzx" AND field_b = "bbb"
```

But you should really think about changing the structure of your table. Having comma-separated values in a single field is not really recommanded.

Instead, you should have for example here an ID for each travel (or whatever it is, I said travel because of the destination field). Then, make an entry for each destination within this travel. With this kind of structure, you'd have a request like this :

```
SELECT destination, COUNT(id) 
FROM demo 
WHERE field_a = "xzx" AND field_b = "bbb" 
GROUP BY destination
```

Comment: The `not using csv fields` is a very good sentiment.  In this case, however, it needs a separate table to avoid repeating the `field_a` and `field_b` values cross multiple rows.

Comment: Indeed, but this solution was just in case he wanted to avoid creating another table, and keep just one with few modifications.

Comment: But repeating those values is also breaking relational database design principles.  In your suggestion `id` can't be a primary key, so can't be foreign keyed to.  Also, if the values in `field_a` or `field_b` change they need updating in many rows, not just one.  This replaces one anti-pattern *(csv fields)* with another anti-pattern *(denormalised dimension tables)*.

Comment: Hmm well I didn't see that on this angle ! Thanks for the advice then

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, that will realy help!

Comment: @expo101 - Then you should up-vote and accept the answer(s) that you deem most helpful to you :)